# Evolution of Greek San from Phoenician Tṣadē

Tags: alphabets

It is generally agreed that the Greek letter *San* developed from the Phoenician *Tṣadē*, but I'm not sure I see the graphical similarity. The Phoenician form [image] does bear some resemblance to the Greek form [image] and even to the more common Greek form [image], but the resemblance doesn't seem that great to me, and there is evidence to suggest that the Greek alphabet was developed at a time when *Tṣadē* was drawn more like a Y, as shown on the Izbet Ṣartah abecedary:

[image]

How did the shape evolve?

Comment: Why do you call it "tṣade" instead of ṣade (or ṣadhe)?

Comment: There's evidence to suggest its sound was [tsʼ]. See https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Semitic_Languages/SMzgBLT87MkC?hl=en&gbpv=1, pg. 69.

Comment: Sure, but the usual way of indicating the phoneme in Semitic studies, at least in my experience, is just plain ṣ.

Comment: FWIW, the modern Hebrew form of the letter is צ medially or initially and ץ finally. Those *do* sort of look like a Y.

Comment: When do you think the Greek alphabet developed?

Comment: beta and pi are also similarly different from their phoenician antecedents to my eyes